# Implicit array passing/creation

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, initialization

I realize this is probably impossible but I will ask any ways.

Suppose I have a class:

```
class A{
  int* array;
 public:
  //To be clear this class has other members
  constexpr int GetSize() { return 10; /*actually this could be a little more than this*/ }
  A(int arr[GetSize()]) : array(arr) { }
};
```

I should declare it like this:

```
int array[A::GetSize()] = { 0 };
A var(array);
```

But I am lazy and want it to be treated as if i did not declare the array at all...like this:

```
A var;
```

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Some constraints:

- No dynamic memory allocation (this is for a micro controller)
- I do not know the actual size of the array until I compile
- The magic array number is derived from the `sizeof(A)` so I cannot include an array in the class because the `sizeof(A)` cannot be determined until after the array size is determined (which needs to know the `sizeof(A)`)
- The `A` class has to be able to be put into templates and initialized that way (this is the main constraint) example:

  ```
  template <class T>
  class Other{
  public:
     T foo(){
        T a;
        return a;
     }
  };

  //Later
  Other<A> other;
  other.foo();  //This must compile
  ```

Comment: Minor issue, `A var();` declares a function called `var` taking no arguments and returning an `A`. You want `A var;` instead

Comment: @Kevin You are correct....oops

Comment: Oh boy, use a `std::vector<int>` or even better a `std::array<int,GetSize()>` where `GetSize()` is a `static constexpr`.

Comment: "no dynamic memory", "do not know size until [runtime]" Sorry, but there's no way in C++ to do what you want. The closest would be to set a template `A<10> var;` or set a reasonable upper bound on the size

Comment: You could make a macro

Comment: @xaxxon If it could work and not violate the "`A` can be put into templates" constraint that will work

Comment: @vu1p3n0x "do not know size until [runtime]" where do you see that?

Comment: @xaxxon that was my reworded interpretation of his second bullet point because "until I compile" may be seen as ambiguous

Comment: @vu1p3n0x You know compile time is before runtime, right?

Comment: @immibis The number depends on some `sizeof`s so I can't tell you what it is until I compile the code (hence the weird wording)

Comment: @DarthRubik so then you can go the template route or just create it as such `int array[sizeof(...)];`

Comment: @vu1p3n0x I cannot do that because the `sizeof(A)` depends on how big the array is (so i can't do that because it creates a circular dependency)

Comment: @DarthRubik oh, you're saying stuff depends sizeof(A) not that the array size depends on sizeof(something_else)

Comment: @vu1p3n0x Yup (unfortunately)

Comment: @DarthRubik _"The magic array number is derived from the `sizeof(A)`"_ You'll need the c++πx library including the brandnew unicorn type reflections.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The sarcasm is strong with this one.....

Comment: @DarthRubik You're calling for my sarcasm every time you write words like _"magic array number"_. C++ doesn't rely on _magic_, but facts.

Comment: I can't tell if you want `array` to be public or private

Comment: @Jfevold private for my implementation (but it should not matter as far as theory goes)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds a lot like you want (at least an equivalent of) something like:

```
using A = std::array<int, size>;

A var;
```

This definitely fits your first two constraints. I can't quite figure out what your third constraint is intended to mean. You can certainly put a object of type `array` into a template, but it's not clear what you're talking about when you say: "and initialized that way". This can be initialized like a normal array, so `A var = {0};` will be fine, if that's what you mean.

Note that although `std::array` was added in C++11, a reasonable analog of it can be written using only C++98 features (e.g., TR1 includes an `array` type that's essentially similar and compatible with C++98/03 compilers).

Comment: The only problem is that `class A` has other members...it just happens to have an array also

Comment: @DarthRubik: Okay, so define a type B (that's similar to `A` in this answer) then include an instance of it in your `A`.

Comment: @But then I have a circular dependency because the number is derived from `sizeof(A)`, which means I can't include an array of length `sizeof(A)` because that is not known until the array size is determined (the same problem exists with declaring a class B and then including that as a member of A)...I will update my constraints to emphasize this

Comment: @DarthRubik XY problem. What are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I don't buy that this is an XY problem. At the very least, it's X vs. Something in Klingon, translated from Tolkein's Elvish by way of Egyptian hieroglyphics. 7 edits, and the real intent still isn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
class B
{
  friend class A;
  int a, b, c; //Whatever you want here
};

class A : public B
{
  int array[(sizeof B)];
public:
  static constexpr int length = (sizeof B) + (sizeof int) * (sizeof B);
};
```

Comment: This actually could work!!!!!!

Comment: took a few edits, but I got there.

Comment: On further inspection this code will not work for me because, you are declaring an array that is the `sizeof(B)` not the `sizeof(A)`... In order to declare an array the size of `A` you would have to know the size of `A` so actually this does not work....This is the reason that I am using a pointer to an array not an array, because the pointer changes the size in a predictable way

Comment: This doesn't give access to the array on the stack when the function is called which the original example does.   It associates the lifetime of the array with the object instead of the calling function.  Not sure if those are requirements, but they are definitely different than the example in the question.

Comment: @xaxxon partially correct (I think), but the OP is withholding any detail whatsoever about why he wants this behavior, so we're left guessing about which technicalities of the original example are relevant.  And I'm enjoying the puzzle.  What I think is incorrect is that you cannot split object lifetime from calling function lifetime if you don't have a heap (another puzzle).

Comment: @DarthRubik So you don't have a heap to work with, so everything must go on the stack or have 'global' lifetime.  If you can live with a set, finite maximum number of A's to be created, it's possible  It is not possible to allocate, with one variable instantiation, both space for the variable and then some extra for it to point to.